# Make a gif-like animation with a bunch of png files using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, animation, png, animated-gif

Despite all of my efforts to make a high quality gif-like animation out of a bunch of png files, I am still getting errors... I have gotten so many of them like "document.getElementById is not a function" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null". I decided to ask what I am doing wrong here. This is an old code that I found somewhere that I've been trying to use:

```
<script>

var min = 1;
var max = 12;
var current = min;

var keep_switching_icon = true;

function rotateIcon() {
  if (keep_switching_icon) {
    var nyanframe = document.getElementById('nyan')
    nyanframe.src = ({path:"nyan" + current + ".png"});
    console.log(current);
    if (current++ > max) {
      current = min;
    };

    window.setTimeout(rotateIcon, 300);
  }
}

rotateIcon();

</script>

<body>

<img src="nyan1.png" id="nyan"></img>

</body>
```

Comment: What is expected result of `nyanframe.src = ({path:"nyan" + current + ".png"});` ?

Comment: thanks, now the image is updating, but it's not changing to the images in the directory... I have images named nyan1.png, nyan2.png,..... nyan12.png. Inspect Element says the image is `[object Object]`...

Comment: I want it to change from nyan1.png to nyan2.png until it gets to nyan12.png, then I want it to start over...

Comment: If you're referring to an answer, comment directly to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting `nyanframe.src = "nyan" + current + ".png";` for `nyanframe.src = ({path:"nyan" + current + ".png"});`

```
var min = 1;
var max = 12;
var current = min;

var keep_switching_icon = true;

function rotateIcon() {
  if (keep_switching_icon) {
    var nyanframe = document.getElementById('nyan');
    nyanframe.src = "nyan" + current + ".png";
    console.log(current);
    if (current++ > max) {
      current = min;
    };

    window.setTimeout(rotateIcon, 300);
  }
}

window.onload = rotateIcon;
```

Comment: Wouldn't an `eventListener` be a better choice instead of `window.onload = rotateIcon;`?